# did buddha accept astrology and other occult science?

Tags: buddha

what about buddhas view on occult science. did he accept or unaccepted these things ?
I personally know some monk also do this things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

buddha not accept or unaccepted occult science.

not said all occult science as **true**

not said occult science as **frauds**

BECAUSE HIS MAIN TEACHING WAS ABOUT NIRVANA...he said don't waste your time for anything and follow nirvana path soon as possible..